# Drupal 6 Location Module get city name using zip code

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I am using Location module and enabled Location CCK field. While creating content I am just collecting zip/postal code and country. I want to display the City name using the zip/postal code associated with node.

I know Location module comes with zip code database. Is there need to query this zip/postal code database to get City name? If that zip/postal code is not available then what could be solution?

Please guide me how could I achieve this?

Comment: Here's an old thread with no sign of any solution: http://groups.drupal.org/node/41862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of it has been resolved. This could be helpful for others.
You can get zip/postal code information by the function available in the location module i.e.
**location_get_postalcode_data** which accept Location parameter as array

```
@param $location
 *   Array. the location data
 *   -> the values are:
 *     'street'         => the string representing the street location (REQUIRED)
 *     'additional'     => the string representing the additional street location portion in the location form
 *     'city'           => the city name (REQUIRED)
 *     'province'       => the province code defined in the country-specific include file
 *     'country'        => the lower-case of the two-letter ISO code (REQUIRED)
 *     'postal_code'    => the postal-code (REQUIRED)
```

Also I did some modification in my country specific **.inc** file available in supported directory to fetch extra information along with default lat-lon info.

But second part if zip/postal code not available in database then is pending.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function 
{
    $null='';
    #   REFERENCE SITE URL = http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html


    #   get and output "<Result>" elements
    $result=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Result');
    foreach ($result as $val)
    {
        return $null;
    }
}
```